# My NSWindow appear only a grey empty view on 10.8.5 OS X

Tags: macos

Can anyone help me pls? When I run my application on 10.9 and 10.10 OS X it looks ok but user that download our app on 10.8.5 OS X say that when open appear only a grey empty screen like in the screenshot (https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7wwkjiqb1xqwmt/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-05%20at%2011.34.00%20AM.png?dl=0).
In AppDelegate I present myWindowController Class(MainWindowController) like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification    
{
// Insert code here to initialize your application

windowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowController"];
[windowController showWindow:self];

}
```

I don't understand what is the problem. Please help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Nothing wrong in this code. Please check your console for any exception coming there .

Comment: Thank you ! I found the problem. In OS X 10.8 can not use the method NSColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: and i replace it with NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha: